# How many bars of supply does it take to make one bar of product?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I just bought the business and all upgrades. How much supply is required for one bar of product?

Comment: Why repeat question if it is in title @Vemonus

Comment: @n_palum there was a pending edit that attempted to change the meaning of the question (they thought the question being asked referred to how much time is taken rather than how much supply was needed), so I repeated the title question to improve clarity. Since I couldn't comment to the editor directly, I left the comment as the edit summary.

Comment: Gotcha! Just wanted to make sure so people weren't getting confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/55vwyl/bikers_work_challenges_contracts_and_business/) post that discusses that DLC in a lot of detail. But to answer your question in short: They estimate it out to be about ~1.25 bars per coke (When fully upgraded).