# Does the game have alternative damage models?

Tags: dirt-rally

The current damage model is very forgiving (I haven't noticed difference in handling with the exception of when  having a flat tire) and allows crashing at extreme speeds (to the game's credit, falling off a clip in Monaco and Greece wrecks your vehicle). Is it possible to disable damage altogether or use a more realistic model, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Steam Forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/310560/discussions/0/485624149171343045/), it does not seem possible to disable damage.  You can read for yourself since its rather to the point, but basically the user asked if you can disable it, to which someone replied "nope," and a bunch of others seem to agree and point out various examples of why you can't.

If you are on PC, it looks like you can try [this mod](http://www.racedepartment.com/downloads/hardcore-damage-model-for-dirt-rally.6657/) (disclaimer: "online events are disabled while the mod is installed") for more realistic damage.  But other than that, it does not appear that you can alter it in any way.

Comment: Deleted mine, we literally posted at the same exact time yet again.

Comment: @n_palum there's no need to delete your answer just because someone else posted the same thing just a fraction of a second before you.  You'll often find that that will happen, and leaving your answer may still warrant you some votes!  (PS: you did that to me on [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300482/163757), however I didn't have my answer written yet but I found that same exact Reddit that you did.  You're welcome for the +1 on that answer ;) )

Comment: Yeah I know.. I can leave it up I guess... it always seems to be the same few people putting up very similar answers quickly, and thanks

Comment: I've added a direct link to the [mod page](http://www.racedepartment.com/downloads/hardcore-damage-model-for-dirt-rally.6657/) with full description and reviews, the notice "RaceNet/online events are disabled while the mod is installed" can now be seen ("RaceNet" is an online feature as far as I know, therefore omitted from the edited answer).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to disable damage all together. Even for the sake of wanting to practice more tracks without having a damaged car, you aren't realistically practicing then.

There is a [steam discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/310560/discussions/0/485624149171343045/) where someone was asking something pretty similar.